# Getting user id from on table and counting them in another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have to make a scores page for a game and one thing it has to display is the number of times the current user has played the game. Basically what i need to select ID and username from one table, link them together and count the corresponding user IDs from another table.
These are the tables I was given: Users --> ID, USERNAME and Times_Played --> ID, USER_ID

Thanks in advance

Comment: post both the table structure together with some sample data along with desired output

Answer (score 2):

[image: SQL Joins]

You want to query something like this:

```
SELECT Users.USERNAME, Times_Played.User_ID
FROM Users
INNER JOIN Times_Played
ON Users.ID=Times_Played.ID;
```

**EDIT**

After re-reading the question and seeing the need to count the times played you could do this via PHP or via your SQL Query. Via PHP:

```
$result = mysqli_query(
"SELECT Users.USERNAME, Times_Played.User_ID
FROM Users
INNER JOIN Times_Played
ON Users.ID=Times_Played.ID"
);

$timesPlayed = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

If it has to be done via the query, Anish has the correct solution.

I hope that helps.

Comment: what about Times_Played ?

Comment: Edited. Thanks for pointing that out. Misread the question at first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select count(*) as Times_Played,Users.USERNAME,Users.ID 
 from Users 
 inner join Times_Played 
 on Users.ID = Times_Played.USER_ID
```